# Need to take item from rss and open it in WebView

Tags: ios, xcode, rss, webview, viewcontroller

Hey this is my code on rootviewcontroller.m (the rss page)

```
NSDictionary* storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];

// clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);


browserScreen=[[BrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BrowserViewController" bundle:nil];
browserScreen.storyLink =[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];

[self.view addSubview:browserScreen.view];
```

This opens WebView page but does not loads the url I requested. Here's my BrowserViewController.m s viewDidload page(web view and i also patched up things at .xib file)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // NSString *urlAddress = storyLink;
    NSString *urlAddress = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"storyLink"];

    //Create a URL object.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Hope someone helps because I feel desperate about it

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code reflects a lot of flailing because you compute a local `storyLink`, clean it up, log it, then ignore it; you set the `storyLink` property of `browserScreen` from the original, un-cleaned-up source; then, in `-viewDidLoad`, you don't even use that, you get a file path from your bundle.

For that last part: given that you have a file path string, you shouldn't use `+URLWithString:` to create a URL from it.  A file path is a not a valid URL string.  You need to use `+fileURLWithPath:`.

Also, you compute the file path as being immediately inside your bundle.  Is that really where the file is?  It's not in Contents/Resources or something like that?